# Memory-compute overlap affects kernel duration?

Tags: cuda, overlap

Profiling my solution, I see dependencies between memory transfer and kernel computation. For a 60Mb data transfer, I have 2ms overhead for each overlapped kernel computation.

I'm computing  my basic solution and the enhanced one (overlapped) to see the differences. They treat the same amount of data with the same kernels (which do not depend on the data value).

So am I wrong or missing something somewhere, or does the overlap really use a "significant" part of the GPU ?

I think the overlapping process must order the data transfer and control its issue and you may add the context switching. But compared to 2ms it seems to be too much ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you overlap data copy with compute, both operations are competing for GPU memory bandwidth.  If your kernel is memory-bandwidth bound, then its possible that overlapping the operations will cause both the compute and the memory copy to run longer, than if either were running alone.

60 megabytes of data on a PCIE Gen2 link will take ~10ms of time if there is no contention.  An extra 2ms when there is contention doesn't sound out-of-range to me, but it will depend to a significant degree, which GPU you are using.  It's also not clear if the "overhead" you're referring to is an extension of the length of the transfer, or the kernel compute, or the overall program.  Different GPUs have different GPU memory bandwidth numbers.

Comment: You might be right, my kernel need a large memory bandwith.
Due to the contention the memory transfer bandwith is also slown down.
Thank you !